# Creating custom ng-model directives mapped to non-json model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create AngularJS directives to be able to manipulate RDF graphs without creating a custom json mapping.

---

**Some basic infos about RDF data structures.**

- An RDF graph is a set of triples Set(subject,predicate,object).
- So an RDF graph can have multiple subjects (~nodes)
- A pointed graph is a graph on which we point to a given subject.
  So it is a (pointedSubject,graph) where the pointedSubject is a subject of the graph.

Exemple of RDF graph describing 2 persons:

```
Graph G1 = 
(Sebastien,familyName,Lorber)
(Sebastien,phoneNumber,046456654)
(Sebastien,email,seb@gmail.com)
(Henry,familyName,Story)
(Henry,phoneNumber,046456654)
(Henry,email,henry@gmail.com)
```

So I can create a pointer to this graph:

PointedGraph PG = (Sebastien,G1)

It's like being on the node Sebastien of a graph which contains 2 nodes: Henry and Sebastien

---

**Back to Angular**

What I'd like to do is to be able to map this graph data (handled by a library) directly in my view.

In pseudo-code it should work a bit like this:

```
<div ng-model="PG">
  <span ng-model="PG.pointedSubject"/>
  <span rdf-predicate="familyName"></span>
  <input rdf-predicate="phoneNumber"/>
  <input rdf-predicate="email"/>
</div>
```

I'm new to Angular and I am not sure how to do this nor have found any similar exemple. I just know that I probably should use the ^ngModel controller in my `rdf-predicate` directive.

I have an API with functions to manipulate the graph data, I can do operations like:

```
getPredicateValue(pointedGraph,predicate);
getPredicateValue(graph,subject,predicate);
changePredicateValue(pointedGraph,predicate,newObjectValue);
changePredicateValue(graph,subject,predicate,newObjectValue);
```

It is probably enough to do a 2-way binding with Angular on this graph object.

Can someone tell me the best way to achieve this please?

---

**Performance considerations**

If my model to represent a person is not a JSON object but rather a pointed graph, if I put a watch on this pointed graph, will it slow down the dirty checking mechanism or something?

Comment: How is the RDF graph represented in javascript?

Comment: @GruffBunny it is a graph using https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js

Comment: If it's a large graph then I imagine putting a watch on it would slow things down considerably, however, the documentation of rdfstore.js shows it also has an events api, so you can let _it_ tell you when and which triples to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've find a solution.

This can be used like this:

```
<div style="clear:both;">
    <h2>Mode edition:</h2>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        Name: <input ng-model="personPG" rdf-predicate-binding="foaf:name"></input><br/>
        Given name: <input ng-model="personPG" rdf-predicate-binding="foaf:givenName"></input><br/>
        Family name: <input ng-model="personPG" rdf-predicate-binding="foaf:familyName"></input><br/>
        Img: <input ng-model="personPG" rdf-predicate-binding="foaf:img"></input><br/>
        Nick: <input ng-model="personPG" rdf-predicate-binding="foaf:nick"></input><br/>
        Mbox: <input ng-model="personPG" rdf-predicate-binding="foaf:mbox"></input><br/>
        Homepage: <input ng-model="personPG" rdf-predicate-binding="foaf:homepage"></input><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the directive is:

```
  .directive('rdfPredicateBinding',['RdfGraphService',function(RdfGraphService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        rdfPredicateBinding: '@rdfPredicateBinding'
      },
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var predicate = scope.rdfPredicateBinding;

        ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function formatter(pointedGraph) {
          if (pointedGraph) {
            var object = RdfGraphService.findFirstObject(pointedGraph.graph,pointedGraph.pointer,predicate);
            return object;
          }
        });

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function parser(value) {
          var pg = scope.ngModel;
          var newGraph = RdfGraphService.createOrReplaceObject(pg.graph,pg.pointer,predicate,value);
          return {
            graph: newGraph,
            pointer: pg.pointer
          }
        });

        // model -> view
        ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
          elm.val(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
        };
      }
    };
  }])
```

However, I'm not sure it's an ideal solution and I wonder how many watches it creates. By the way, the PointedGraph may perhaps be a complicated object to watch